# Is there any way to get stop a rigidbody2d from accelerating in unity2d (beginner)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple 2d platformer game, and dont understand how to really do the movement. So far, I have just used transform.position += transform.left, etc etc, and it has worked, except that sometimes it phases through walls, so I recently started using an addforce command but it has acceleration is there any way to remove this?

Comment: Go with [Rigidbody.velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)

Comment: I would do this, but I have jumping, and the velocity is always changing